# Asp.NET dropdownlist direction

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Is it possible with the standard asp:dropdownlist to make the list expand upwards instead of downwards, or do I need to create a custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know the standard dropdown expand downwards if there is enough space to do it otherwise it expands upwards

So the answer is: you would need a custom control :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a custom control.  The ASP.Net dropdownlist is just a wrapper for the basic HTML select list.

If you list some more details as to what/why you need that functionality, we may be able to provide further suggestions.